# Python - Beautifulsoup, check for a child element with specific condition inside a find_all() result

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've got a situation where I need to check if a specific link appears in a list of elements inside of a table row, ex:

```
<td class="TableRow">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;"> #I use this as my current selector for the find_all() method
    <a href="http://internallink1.com"> 
      <img src="/images/pdf-icon.png" title="Infos">
    </a>
    <a href="https://externallink1.com">
      <img src="/images/web-icon.png" title="">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>

<td class="TableRow">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <a href="https://externallink2.com">
      <img src="/images/web-icon.png" title="">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>

<td class="TableRow">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <a href="https://externallink3.com">
      <img src="/images/web-icon.png" title="">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>
```

What I'm actually trying to accomplish is to check for all of the existing elements inside the table, check if any internal link exist, then print all of the "external link" instances where an internal link DOESN'T EXIST, so that my output is:

```
>"https://externallink2.com"
>"https://externallink3.com"
```

**My approache**

```
list = soup.find_all("span", {"style" : "white-space: nowrap;"})
for x in list:
  if (condition): #if span doesn't contain internal link, or you can also use "pdf-icon.png"
    print x       #x == externallink
  else:           #if span contains an internal link
    pass
```

I can't seem to find any specific documentation for this on the web so any kind of help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks  --- Some of your code would be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for the `src` or the `title` of the icon, if this is the criteria - Please, do not use python keywords as variable names (e.g. list)

To get the `src` of your icon you can use:

```
x.find('img')['src']
```

or

```
x.img['src']
```

Compare it against the string of the icon for internal links:

```
if x.img['src'] == '/images/web-icon.png':
    do something...
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<td class="TableRow">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;"> #I use this as my current selector for the findAll() method
    <a href="http://internallink1.com"> 
      <img src="/images/pdf-icon.png" title="Infos">
    </a>
    <a href="https://externallink1.com">
      <img src="/images/web-icon.png" title="">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>

<td class="TableRow">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <a href="https://externallink2.com">
      <img src="/images/web-icon.png" title="">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>

<td class="TableRow">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <a href="https://externallink3.com">
      <img src="/images/web-icon.png" title="">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for x in soup.find_all("span", {"style" : "white-space: nowrap;"}):
    if x.img['src'] == '/images/web-icon.png': #if span doesn't contain internal link, or you can also use "pdf-icon.png"
        print(x.a['href'])      #x == externallink
    else:           #if span contains an internal link
        pass
```

**Output**

```
https://externallink2.com
https://externallink3.com
```

Comment: I can't really grasp how, but I just tried it and it worked, thanks so much, I'll try to read some more documentation about beautifulsoup since there seem to be a lot of ways of selecting elements that I'm unaware of